# SQLite Android NDK add custom functions

Tags: android, c++, c, sqlite, android-ndk

I have managed to get SQLite setup using the NDK, but I can't manage to get custom functions to work which was the whole reason for implementing SQLite using the NDK.

I used [this](https://github.com/moneymanagerex/SQLite-Android-Bindings) library to get the same SQLite files. It also contains an extension file called [extensionfunctions.c](https://github.com/moneymanagerex/SQLite-Android-Bindings/blob/master/jni/sqlite/extensionfunctions.c) which adds in string and mathematical functions for SQLite.

From what I can see, the SQLite implementation appears to be working correctly, but I cannot call any of the custom functions.

I've little to no knowledge of C/C++, so any help would be great. Do I have to compile the extensionfunctions.c file independently, and then add in the SO file with the libsqliteX.so file? Or do I have to make a call in the android_database_SQLiteCommon.cpp to load in the other extension? I've no idea how this works.

**Edit**

The file extensionfunctions.c is included in sqlite3secure.c which is in the Android.mk file under LOCAL_SRC_FILES. I assume that means the file is being used correctly, but none of the custom functions are accessible.

**Edit 2**

```
// To enable the extension functions define SQLITE_ENABLE_EXTFUNC on compiling this module

#ifdef SQLITE_ENABLE_EXTFUNC
#define sqlite3_open    sqlite3_open_internal
#define sqlite3_open16  sqlite3_open16_internal
#define sqlite3_open_v2 sqlite3_open_v2_internal
#endif

#include "sqlite3.c"

#ifdef SQLITE_ENABLE_EXTFUNC
#undef sqlite3_open
#undef sqlite3_open16
#undef sqlite3_open_v2
#endif
```

I found the above code with the comment and I added in the line below but it appears as though nothing has changed.

```
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_EXTFUNC
```

Do I have to do anything to get the app to refresh it's version of the sqlite3 files or could that be a problem? My C skills are poor so I assume what I did is what the comment has referring to?